# Why when making start a new game when it's loading the game scene over again it also remember one flag state as true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The content is a bit long but all the three scripts parts are connected.

In one script if in the game the player enters the correct code a `public static flag m_hasOpened` becomes `true`:

```
private void HandleInputCode(int inputCode)
{
    if (inputCode == _targetCode)
    {
        Debug.Log("Code correct!", this);
        anim.Play("Crate_Open");
        m_hasOpened = true;
```

And in the same script I return this f lag from a method :

```
public bool HasOpened()
{
    return m_hasOpened;
}
```

Then in another script I'm checking if this flag is `true`. If it's opened means the `m_hasOpened` is `true` then set another `public static` flag to `true`:

```
if (allDetectedItems.Count == 2)
{
    objectsNames = allDetectedItems.Select(item => item.transform.name).ToList();
    if (objectsNames.Contains("NAVI") && objectsNames.Contains("Security Keypad"))
    {
        InteractableItem navi = allDetectedItems.Single(item => item.transform.name == "NAVI");
        InteractableItem securitykeypad = allDetectedItems.Single(item => item.transform.name == "Security Keypad");
        var crate = GameObject.Find("Crate_0_0");

        var test = crate.gameObject.GetComponent<UnlockCrate>().HasOpened();
        if (crate.gameObject.GetComponent<UnlockCrate>().HasOpened())
        {                        
            primaryTarget = navi;
            var rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
            startMovingNAVI = true;
        }
```

Now `startMovingNAVI` is `true`.

In a third script I'm start moving the NAVI is `startMovingNAVI` is `true`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveNavi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rig_f_middle;
    public float speed;
    public float distanceFromTarget;
    public static bool naviChildOfHand = false;
    public GameObject naviParent;
    public bool startedFade = false;
    public FadeInOut fadeInOut;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true && startedFade == false)
        {
            var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
            if (v.magnitude < distanceFromTarget)
            {                
                startedFade = true;
                StartCoroutine(fadeInOut.Fade(FadeInOut.FadeDirection.Out));
                StartCoroutine(fadeInOut.Fade(FadeInOut.FadeDirection.In));

                naviChildOfHand = true;

                return;
            }
            Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
            transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeChild()
    {
        var parent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
        transform.parent = parent.transform;
        transform.localPosition = parent.transform.localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
    }
}
```

Now I press once the escape key back to the main menu so it's loading the main menu scene and removing the game scene. In the main menu I click on start a new game button :

```
public void ClickNewGameDialog(string ButtonType)
{
    if (ButtonType == "Yes")
    {
        loading = false;
        newGameDialog.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(sceneFader.FadeAndLoadScene(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, _newGameButtonLevel));
    }

    if (ButtonType == "No")
    {
        GoBackToMainMenu();
    }
}
```

And last in the SceneFader script :

```
public IEnumerator FadeAndLoadScene(FadeDirection fadeDirection, string sceneToLoad)
{
    yield return Fade(fadeDirection);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);

    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
}

private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
{
    if (MenuController.loading == true)
    {
        var saveLoad = GameObject.Find("Save System").GetComponent<SaveLoad>();
        saveLoad.Load();

        MenuController.loading = false;
    }
}
```

When it's a new game it's just loading the game scene the flag loading is `false`, but when it's loading the game scene as a new game for some reason in the MoveNavi script `startMovingNavi` is `true`:

```
if (IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true && startedFade == false)
```

Why is it `true`? If I started a new game without loading anything it should be `false`.

When I quit the game app in the editor not escape to the main menu just quit the app it self and then run over the game again and make a new game it's `false` and fine but in the game while the game is running if I make escape key then new game he remember this flag as `true`.

And I used a breakpoint it's never setting it to `true` again it's just `true` already in the MoveNavi script. and it happens only when making a new game while the game is running.

Strange because it's not remembering for example the flag `startedFade` as `true` but the flag `startMovingNAVI` he remember it as `true`.

```
if (IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true && startedFade == false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've told us that `IKControl.startMovingNAVI` is a static field, while `startFade` is not static.

And therein lies your issue. `IKControl.startMovingNAVI` will remain set to the last value you give it for the lifetime of your app. Unity will generally unload the app when it has to do a domain reload (for instance recompiling any changed scripts) but static variables do need more care when developing inside the Unity Editor.

From what I can tell of your code, you don't need `IKControl.startMovingNAVI` to be a static field. You could have a reference to your IKControl instance on your MoveNavi script. Then simply drag your IKControl component into the corresponding object field.

```
[SerializeField] private IKControl ikControl;
```

And in you IKControl script, make a few modifications to your code.

```
public bool startMovingNavi { get; private set; }
```

Now use `ikControl.startMovingNAVI` wherever you've been using `IKControl.startMovingNAVI`.

I'm also unsure if in your first (unnamed) script you need `m_hasOpened` to be static either. You could probably do away with that in the same fashion.

```
public bool hasOpened { get; private set; }
```

After doing this, and removing the static variables, you should find that your code won't be retaining the values from previous runs of the game.

Comment: What does [SerializeField] do ? Why not using public instead ? public IKControl ikControl; why in this case I would use [SerializeField] ?

Comment: What serialising a private field does is not pollute your MoveNavi script with public variables. It's not required, but it's not bad. You COULD just have a public field, but when you start looking at an instance of your MoveNavi from another script, your Intellisense will give you access to all sorts of fields you simply "shouldn't" have access to. Another way to look at it is, it's to help you not break your code.